# Replicate views from Postgres to Postgres on AWS DMS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I'm using AWS DMS to migrate data from one Postgres database to another Postgres database. Everything works fine, except one thing: the views are no replicated on my target database.

I've read that this cannot be done between heterogenous database (i.e. from Oracle to Postgres) using DMS, but I imagine that this is possible somehow when we're using the same database.

Does someone know how to replicate the views using AWS DMS from Postgres to Postgres?

Answer (score 6):

DMS is a **data** migration service. View is a virtual table(represented by sql code/object) and it does not contain any data by itself like a table does.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't looking to migrate the actual DDL but instead were happy to replicate the data from views in the source to tables in the target (akin to materialising the views in the target) then you can do this, but you need to jump into JSON configuration and there's some caveats.

Per the [Selection rules and actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Selections.html) portion of the DMS documentation, you can add to the `object-locator` object a `table-type` field, setting its value to one of `view` or `all` to migrate views. It defaults to `table` which skips views, and there's no configuration field for it in the console aside from modifying the JSON.

For example:

```
{
  "rule-type": "selection",
  "rule-id": "123456",
  "rule-name": "some-rule",
  "object-locator": {
    "schema-name": "my_schema",
    "table-name": "%",
    "table-type": "view"
  },
  "rule-action": "include",
  "filters": []
}
```

There are a couple of caveats though:

- Not all sources support migrating views. Aurora PostgreSQL doesn't, for instance, and saving the task will give an error if you try so you may need to replace the endpoint with a vanilla PostgreSQL one
- If you're migrating views, your only option is a full load - CDC isn't going to work, so partial migrations aren't on the cards
- Migrating views [doesn't appear to be supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Serverless.Limitations.html) *at all* with DMS Serverless - you'll get an error akin to "Views isn't supported for serverless yet" (their grammar, not mine)

Comment: This was right on target.  Adding "table-type": "view" to the JSON definition of source table did the trick.  Instead of DMS looking for a table, it used the view from the source and created the table on the target.